# В разделе “Отзывы на сообщение” названия табов не консистентны

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора, 10k-tools

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/overrated?filter=all

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно к одной форме всё привести. Предлагаю написать "завышенные".
Добавил предложение в традусёре: https://ru.traducir.win/string/8007